# InertiaJS (VueJS) + Laravel no data displayed to page

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have no idea why the data is not displayed on my page. Instead when i'm inspecting elements only showing this :

```
<body>
    <div id="app" data-page="{&quot;component&quot;:&quot;Welcome&quot;,&quot;props&quot;:{&quot;errors&quot;:{},&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Superman&quot;},&quot;url&quot;:&quot;\/&quot;,&quot;version&quot;:&quot;&quot;}"></div>

</body>
```

This is my route :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Welcome', [
        'name' => 'Superman'
    ]);
});
```

This is my Welcome.vue :

```
 <script setup>
 defineProps({
 name: string,
 });
</script>
 
<template>
    <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
</template>
```

i have run npm install , import any script related to vuejs. nothing seem to works

Comment: Have you followed this guide (https://inertiajs.com/server-side-setup) to get set up? Please also include the code for your root template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code:

```js
defineProps({
  name: string,
});
```

It cause error `ReferenceError: string is not defined`. Then, I capitalize `string` to `String` and it works.

Is that the problem you are having?

Comment: Thanks! it works now. I should be aware of that.

Comment: In that case, you can mark the answer as accepted to that everyone knows this question has been already solved.